# Native select...in() clause with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have found that using a very common query like this:

`@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="select * from questions where id in (22,45,65,777,444)")` results in a list of objects instead of a list of questions object.

`[[Ljava.lang.Object;@49fd8d8f, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2558cd3c, [Ljava.lang.Object;@690a314b]`

How is this situation going to be fixed?

How can I manage this right now?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
@RooJpaRepository(domainType = Challenge.class)
public interface ChallengeRepository extends ChallengeRepositoryCustom
{
    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="select * from questions where id in (22,45,65,777,444)")
    List<Questions> chooseRandomOldQuestions();
}
```

Comment: Why use a native query? The JPQL `select q from Question q where q.id in (22,45,65,777,444)` will return a `List<Question>`

Comment: No. It's an basic query example to demonstrate it with spring-data-jpa, but mi query is much more complex than this one so must be created in a native mode. I have show this one to focus on the problem.

Comment: What does your repository interface look like?

Comment: I have edited it to show you the important part of my repo, thanks. Every query is finding in a correct way (I have even custom repositories) so I think is a problem related to the 'in' clause.

Comment: To test it you can try to execute any native query that contains the 'in' clause and you will see that the object is retrieved but not in a typed way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly feel like this has nothing to do with the `in` clause but the types you use.

Your repository is typed to the `Challenge` domain class. `Question` (I guess you mean that rather than `Questions`) is probably not a sub type of `Challenge` right? If this is the case we do not hand the domain type to the `EntityManager` to accommodate scenarios where people execute projections to `Long` etc. and the query execution would fail if we handed a non-managed type to the query execution.

The workaround is to create a dedicated repository managing `Question(s)` instances (still not sure this is a typo or a separate class) should do the trick.

Comment: The Challenge has a Set<Questions>. Is it what you mean sub type? If I try to get only one Question object in the query everything is fine.

Comment: In addition, I am able of retrieving any kind of object (being a subtype or not) in any of my repos, this issue is only appearing when I use the 'in' clause.

Comment: That cannot be the case. With subtype I mean subtype in the inheritance way. If you use a native query *and* don't have a subtype of the repositories root type returned you'll see the native types (read: `Map`s, `Long`s etc.). This seems to be the case here as `Questions` doesn't seem to be a subtype of `Challenge` (as indicated in my answer already.

Comment: OK. The point here a is the use of native query as I see. I will create a new repository and try it again...thanks Oliver!